# class variables - alignment

Tags: c++, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Classes store data members in sequential memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352373/classes-store-data-members-in-sequential-memory)

Just wanted to ask why the following is correct:

```
template<class T>
class Vec3 {
public:
  // values
  T x,y,z;

  // returns i-th komponent (i=0,1,2) (RHS array operator)
  const T operator[] (unsigned int i) const {
    return *(&x+i);
  }
}
```

or in other words: Why is it always guaranteed that x, y and z are always sizeof(T) units apart in memory. Can't there ever be fragmentation holes in between two of those varibles, thus letting this operator return a false value?

Comment: If you need indexing, why not make it `template <typename T> class Vector3 { public: std::array<T, 3> xs; };`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is **not** guaranteed that `x`, `y` and `z` are always `sizeof(T)` units apart in memory. There can be padding bytes added in between.
It is left out as an implementation detail.
Only thing guaranteed is that there will be no padding between beginning of the class/structure  and its first member for POD structures/classes.

It is not guaranteed that the implementation of `operator[]` in your code will work always.

**Reference:**
C++11: 9.2 Class members [class.mem]

> 14) Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control (Clause 11) are allocated so
>   that later members have higher addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of non-static data
>   members with different access control is unspecified (11). **Implementation alignment requirements might
>   cause two adjacent members not to be allocated immediately after each other;** so might requirements for
>   space for managing virtual functions (10.3) and virtual base classes (10.1).

Comment: What do you mean by "It is left out as an implementation detail."?

Comment: Even the guarantee concerning the address of the first member is only valid for POD structs.  (Or maybe for layout compatible structs in C++11.)

Comment: @AdamMagaluk: It means that the compiler is free to add as many bytes of padding required in between class/structure members. The standard does not mandate any specific requirement in this regard.

Comment: @JamesKanze: one notable counter-example to Alok's statement being polymorphic class since the `v-ptr` is stashed as the first element of the class in the Itanium ABI.

Comment: @JamesKanze, Matthieu: Thanks, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid *fragmentation holes* you can control the alignment this way:

```
#ifdef compiling_with_msvc
#pragma pack(1)
#endif
template<class T>
class Vec3 {
public:
    // values
    T x,y,z;

    // returns i-th komponent (i=0,1,2) (RHS array operator)
    const T operator[] (unsigned int i) const {
        return *(&x+i);
    }
#ifdef compiling_with_gcc
}__attribute__((packed));
#else
};
#endif
```

If you can use a [C++11 compiler](https://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport) you can control the alignment in a [standard way](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#align).

But if you don't care about the memory representation of the class, think about to use an `union`:

```
template <typename T>
union Vec3
{
    T x, y, z;
    struct
    {
        T value[3];
    } vector;
};
```

With the union, you don't have to care about the alignment in order to acces each component with `[]`:

```
Vec3<unsigned int> v3;

v3.vector.value[0] = 1;
v3.vector.value[1] = 2;
v3.vector.value[2] = 3;
```

Comment: Is it actually specified somewhere that, in your union-solution, the fields will be aligned (e.g. x and value[0], y and value[1])? It makes *sense*, but is this actually specified/guaranteed anywhere?

Comment: Yes, `x` and `value[0]`, `y` and `value[1]` ... will have the same address... but I cannot garantee that between `x` <-> `y`, `value[0]` <-> `value[1]` you will found padding bytes; it will depend of the data type, data alignment and alignment control of the `union`